# run powershell command using csv as input

Tags: powershell, csv, windows-live-id

I have a csv that looks like

> Name, email, address
>   Name, email, address
>   Name, email, address

I am wanting to run 
`New-Mailbox -Name "*Name*" -WindowsLiveID *email* -ImportLiveId`

(where `*x*` is replaced by the value from the csv).

on each line in the csv file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\path\to\your.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    New-Mailbox -Name $line.Name -WindowsLiveID $line.Email -ImportLiveId
}
```

First line of csv has to be something like Name,Email,Address

If you cannot have the header in the CSV, you can also have:

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\path\to\your.csv -Header @("Name","Email","Address")
```

-Header doesn't modify the csv file in any way.

Answer (score 3):

```
import-csv .\file.csv  -header ("first","second","third") | foreach{New-Mailbox -Name $_.first -WindowsLiveID $_.second -ImportLiveId}
```

Comment: does -header add a header column?

Comment: -Header doesn't modify the csv file, but it will add a virtual header

Answer (score -5):

This is some of the most useful information I have seen yet - it just made my job so much easier!!!

Combining Netapp commands:

## get volumes from a controller, get snapshot schedule for said volumes, and export to a csv:

get-navol | Get-NaSnapshotSchedule | Export-Csv -path d:\something.csv

## Import the csv reading in current values and assigning each column a label.

## For each object, create a new schedule by RE-USING 4 of the 5 available columns/data fields

import-csv d:\something.csv -header ("label1","label2","label3","label4","label5") | foreach {Set-naSnapshotschedule $*.label1 -Weeks $*.label2 -Days $*.label3 -Hours $*.label4 -Whichhours "1,2,3,4,5"}

EXCELLENT STUFF!!!

Please note that the "Labels" should have an underscore - for whatever reason it isn't reflecting in the page so Dollar($)Underscore(_)Dot(.)Label