# Powershell - how to pass csv fields as parameters

Tags: python, powershell, csv

I have a problems that I'm trying to solve, but can't seem to figure the key part out. We have tons of records that we process every day using a .jar file, but the problem is that we have to go one by one and that is time consuming. I think we can cut a tremendous amount of time if we use a powershell script.

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the parameters from a csv to a function in powershell.

My csv looks like this

```
NAME,ID                                                                                                                                                                   
-------                                                                                                                                                                   
John,18                                                                                                                                                                     
Dave,19                                                                                                                                                    
Carmen,20                                                                                                                                                       
Eric,21                                                                                                                                                                    
Tom,22                                                                                                                                                          
Lisa,23                                                                                                                                                          
Kyle,24
```

The function is

```
function CreateUser 
& java -jar --create -user $name -id $id -file D:/HR/$name-$id-form.pdf
```

I imported the csv file using

```
$dataCSV = "D:\HR\Input\20150303NewUsers.csv"
$data = Import-Csv $dataCSV
```

So I need something that will go systematically down the file and pass the name field inside the csv as $name and the ID field as $id over and over again until completed. But I can't figure out how to pass those two down on a ForEach-Object method :(

I'm stuck... I've been fighting this all weekend, but nothing.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated! Or if anyone know how to do this in python, that will be cool too! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [run powershell command using csv as input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785117/run-powershell-command-using-csv-as-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a tool that steps through a table (imported from a csv file) and generates an expansion of a template for each row in the table.  One thing I do is to copy each of the values in the row to a powershell variable of the same name as the column.  This may help you.

Here is the tool that I wrote:

```
<#  This scriptlet is a table driven template tool. 
    It's a refinement of an earlier attempt.

    It generates an output file from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table has
    one column for each variable, and one row for each
    expansion to be generated.

    2/15/2015

#>

param ($driver, $template, $out);

$OFS = "`r`n"
$list = Import-Csv $driver
[string]$pattern = Get-Content $template
Clear-Content $out -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach ($item in $list) {
   foreach ($key in $item.psobject.properties) {
      Set-variable -name $key.name -value $key.value
      }
   $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($pattern)  >> $out
   }
```

The part that may interest you is the innner loop, where I do a Set-Variable that matches the column name with the actual value.

Comment: Thank you Walter! this is also a great idea!!

Comment: Thanks. I was going to add a sample run of the tool, but I decided that this would be off topic.  If somebody asks, I'm prepared to do this.

Comment: Glad you worked out a comment to build a real answer +1 for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if typo  but your `D:\...` needs to be enclosed in quotation marks, you haven't closed it off.

Once `$data` holds the list of imported values simply do `foreach ($item in $data) {do something}`

Where `$item` is any word (variable) you want, it simply refers to each row in the CSV.

So...

```
$data = Import-Csv "D:\importfile.csv"
foreach( $item in $data )
{
    # Do-whatever
}
```

Comment: Yup, sorry it is a typo.  The problem I'm still facing is how to pass the name and ID as variables to the foreach

Comment: Sure, so it would be $item.ID where $item is the row and ID is a column header.  In your example you have both $item.name and $item.ID
Such as

       {New-Aduser -identity $item.name -ID $item.ID}

Answer (score 0):

This script will extract values underneath the Name header and place them inside $name variable. Then it will place the values underneath the ID header and place them inside the $id variable.

```
$data = import-csv -path 'D:\HR\Input\20150303NewUsers.csv'

foreach($item in $data)
{
    $name = $item.Name
    $id = $item.ID 
}
```